# DO NOT redirect just render the login layout

Tags: magento

> From my clients, they wanna all customers (users) SHOULD login before visiting any page on Magento site.

I know that if I do that, I have to check if a user does not login, we will redirect to
`customer/account/login`

I have question is:

**I don't wanna redirect, I just wanna render login layout.<sup>(1)</sup>**

So, how can I do that?

---

(1): I see in admin side, it has this behavior, when I try to visit any page of admin side. If the user did not login, or out session, it will render login layout, without redirect.

Comment: Which Magento version? If Enterprise Edition: EE has a "Private Sales: Login only" mode builtin. You just need to activate it (System -> Configuration -> General -> Website Restrictions).

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen: I use Community version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need add next code to your controller action:

```
if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $this->_forward('login', 'account', 'customer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the login page layout description, build a block, and render as HTML.