# How to load the layout at runtime in Magento?

Tags: magento

I know that we can design the layout in `*.xml` then in the `action` just invoke `loadLayout`, and `renderLayout` to render the `blocks/views`.

But, I have a question is:

> #### - How can I load the layout at runtime?
>
> If we have an action which does not really design its layout and will be decided how to render at runtime.

You can please consider [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596756/do-not-redirect-just-render-the-login-layout#7596922) from [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596756/do-not-redirect-just-render-the-login-layout) for more clear.

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked here.

Comment: @AlanStorm: For example, if at: `catalog/product/view/id/16` I dont wanna render the page to display the product has id is 16, I wanna render the view of `customer/account/login` without redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a new answer because it seems that you actually DO still want to render, you just want to render a different route's layout XML updates. I believe the `_forward()` method from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` will allow you to do what you are describing with the least amount of pain.

You should add your action controller directory ahead of the catalog directory, create a ProductController with a viewAction, and check customer is not logged in - in this check you would call `$this->_forward('customer','account','login');`.

This approach though is going to require more effort in order to be usable, as I imagine that you want the user to be sent to the product page upon login.  Have you seen [Vinai Kopp's Login Only Catalog module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vinai/extension/490/login-only-catalog)? It should do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

`loadLayout()` and `renderLayout()` just execute block output method `toHtml()` (usually) and take the resulting strings and apply them to the response object via `appendBody()`. In an action controller you can just call `$this->getResponse()->setBody('response string')`. How you build the string is up to you.

You can also use `Mage_Core_Block_Flush` to immediately send output to the browser without using the response object.

Comment: Love your answer. But this does not seem the question which I need.